# show posts with And relation in categories at WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to show posts which have categories (a,b and c) with And Relation in query.
I wrote the below code but it shows all the posts that have each of categories. How to show those posts that have all 3 categories with And relation?

```
     <?php
    $args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post' ,
    'orderby' => 'date' ,
    'order' => 'DESC' ,
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
     'relation' => 'And',
      'category_name'=>'a','b','c',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_parent' => $parent
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args2);
   if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
    echo the_title();
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: please help, I need it :(

Comment: Posted my anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a tax query, now it checks if a post has categorie a, b or parent of b and the location set.

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        // If 'a' is set.
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'a' ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        // AND if 'b' OR 'parent_b' is set.
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'b', 'parent_b' ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        // AND if location is set.
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    )
);

$q = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        echo the_title();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but it doesn't work. with 'field' => 'name' it doesn't show anything and with 'field' => 'ID' and putting IDs in array it only shows the posts of the first category. 
I'll be very happy if anybody knows how to resolve it.

Comment: I changed the query in my anwser, could you try again? For me it is working.

Comment: And are you sure categories 'a', 'b' and 'c' are all checked?

Comment: Could you also check if the slugs of category a, b and c are a, b and c?

Comment: thank you, it is working. but I have another issues I posted as an answer.